# change to columns and remove columns csv shell

Tags: shell

I have a csv file containing several hundred lines of data. I want to be able to insert a line on top  remove the columns that has the name for the data and then put the name of the data on top of the data value column. and then convert it to text to columns delimited by space.  I am looking to have this done in shell.  see before and after exp below.

Before: One line of data

```
work_needs_to_get_done_001 time 25000000 runs 28908331 other_data1 89708097   
work_needs_to_get_done_002 time 25000000 runs 27285458 other_data1 89708097   
work_needs_to_get_done_003 time 25000000 runs 27284897 other_data1 89708097  
work_needs_to_get_done_004 time 25000000 runs 27280741 other_data1 89708097
```

After: individual columns delimited by space

```
Workname                   Time     Runs      Other_data1   Other_data2 
work_needs_to_get_done_001 25000000 28908331  89708097      89708097  
work_needs_to_get_done_002 25000000 27285458  89708097      89708097
work_needs_to_get_done_003 25000000 27284897  89708097      89708097
work_needs_to_get_done_004 25000000 27280741  89708097      89708097
```

Comment: Did you try to write some script?

Comment: I wrote the script that gives me first set of data, the csv file.  now my brain hurts.  i will start on it.  thought to start with some ideas.

Comment: Do you want header row to be aligned with rest of the rows as shown above?

Answer (score 1):

When need to treat columns comes, think of using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '{print $1, $3, $5, $6}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Workname Time Runs  Other_data1 Other_data2" > 1.txt
awk '{ print $1, $3,$5,$7 }' filename >> 1.txt
```

**For formatting:**

```
awk '{ printf "%-40s %-20s\n %-20 %-20 %-20", $1, $2,$3,$4}'  1.txt
```